# Pygame player movement is being weird

Tags: python, pygame

I was making a pygame project and i made a square move and It would summon a square every frame and there would just be a line of squares.

I tried to update the screen every frame (Because i hadn't yet), but that did not work. Here is my code:

```
#Import Pygame
import pygame

#screen object(width, height)

screen_x = 750
screen_y = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_x, screen_y))

#Set the caption of the screen

pygame.display.set_caption('Game')

#Define a velocity, x, and y variable
velocity = 2.5x = 0.0y = 0.0

#Variable to keep our game loop running

running = True

#Game loop

while running:

   # Initialing Color
   color = (255,0,0)

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w]:
        y += 2.5

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_s]:
        y -= 2.5 


    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= 2.5 


    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_d]:
        x += 2.5 

# Drawing Rectangle
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(x, y, 50, 50))
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.update()
# for loop through the event queue
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # Check for QUIT event  
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire scene is redrawn in every frame, therefore you have to clear the display in every frame:

```py
import pygame

#screen object(width, height)
screen_x = 750
screen_y = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_x, screen_y))

#Set the caption of the screen
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')

#Define a velocity, x, and y variable
velocity = 2.5
x, y = 0, 0
color = (255,0,0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(100)
    # for loop through the event queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Check for QUIT event  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()   
    x += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * velocity
    y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * velocity

    # clear display
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0)) 

    # Drawing Rectangle               
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(x, y, 50, 50))

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple. You forgot to fill the screen with a color. Because your code just draw's a square to the screen surface every frame, and that's why it's drawing a line of squares. You have to fill the screen before drawing the things, because otherwise you will see an empty screen with that color, that you filled the surface with. Hope it helped.

Comment: What is the difference to my answer?